# Adjusting P-Values of one-tailed tests

Tags: t-test, p-value, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, adjustment, one-tailed-test

I am running a large number of two-sample Wilcox tests and using  Benjamini, Hochberg, and Yekutieli method to adjust the p-values.

The issue is that when I conduct a one-tailed test, the p-values before the adjustment satisfy p-value(>) + p-value(<) = 1, which makes sense. After the adjustment, however, this relation is not satisfied any more, and on top of that, in some tests, the alternative hypothesis is accepted in both directions. That is the p-value(X>Y) > 0.95 and p-value(Y>X) > 0.95 ! (Both are one-tailed tests)

So my question is: Is it valid to adjust p-values of one-tailed tests? If yes, how to make sense of the result?

Edit: Sorry, I cannot comment yet since I do not have the necessary reputation.
The reason I am running both directions is: first, to make sure that the adjustment makes sense (which does not seem to be the case as far as I can tell). The second reason is to have a clear display of the results: I want a matrix where I can read columns-wise or row-wise and see which sample is significantly smaller or larger than the other. A two-tailed test will only tell whether the means are different, and I have to check the value of the means in another table to see which sample is actually smaller.

Comment: Are you testing BOTH whether X>Y and whether Y>X? If so, why not use a two-tailed test instead?

Comment: why do  you want to adjust p- values ? And does pv stands for p-value.

Comment: what is your hypothesis that you are planing to test through two sample tests  that you are conducting right now ?

Comment: That is p-value(X>Y) > 0.95 and p-value(Y>X) > 0.95 ? what do you mean ? Does it mean both directions or two tailed ?

Comment: p-value(>) + p-value(<) = 1, which makes sense. what is the meaning of the  equation ? Is p- value a proportion or it represents the probability?  Also, ontailed (and two tailed test) as you perceive  them  creates a lot  of confusion while trying to understand what you are looking for. Be  brief. You appear to be working on adjustment of p values which could be interpreted as probability values or proportions. Do not be presumptive ? Show your results if you want to have a good response from users at this site.